# Is it possible for a method in Java 8 to determine simply whether an Iterable<Integer> Object provides a PrimitiveIterator.OfInt iterator?

Tags: java-8, iterator, iterable

This is my first activity here, I hope I behave correctly! My problem: I am trying to write a collection of functions (static methods in a class) that accept one or several `Iterable<Integer>` and obtains the primitiveIterator.ofInt, providing it to another function that constructs yet another iterator (i.e. the functions are meant to compose iterators in various ways).

Here is a simple example of what I have in mind:

```
public static FilterIteratorInt filtor(Iterable<Integer> iter, IntPredicate filter)
{
    return new FilterIteratorInt((PrimitiveIterator.OfInt)iter.iterator(),filter);
}
```

To me, it is not quite clear whether this can work at all, because the `iterator` returned by the `Iterable<Integer>` Object might not be of type `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt`.

In order to overcome this potential difficulty, I have been looking for a solution, which might either be an Interface like e.g. `PrimitiveIterable.OfInt` or any other way to find out whether the iterator is in fact primitive. I have been searching for quite a while, but while usually just browsing answers nearly all of my question, this time I had to register here to ask that question directly.

This construction is meant to avoid boxing/unboxing orgies, since I want the new iterators to be reasonably fast.

So here are three questions:

1. Is there a way to find out whether the iterator obtained from an iterable is in fact a primitive iterator (such that the function can distinguish and act accordingly) *or* is there another way to obtain one?
2. Is it possibly useless to try to improve performance this way? I.e. will (JIT or Java)compilers optimize this anyway, or is boxing/unboxing unavoidable anyway under the hood? Here I hope to learn something.
3. Can somebody show me a different and better solution that could serve the same purpose (i.e. composition of primitive iterators, or of any iterators, while we are at it)?

**Update:** Due to Holgers answer, it boils down to the following question nr. 4: If `next()` is called on a `PrimitiveInteger.OfInt`, will this invoke the `nextInt()` method, or in other words: Will this automatically end up returning a pure `int`? Or will it still cause a boxing and unboxing sequence?

From the answer below I assume the latter, and this would mean it is definitely better to deal with `nextInt()` explicitly.

Assuming that this is correct (please tell me if I am wrong), I have used the `instanceof` method below and explicitly wrap if required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could simply use `iterator instanceof PrimitiveIterator.OfInt` to test, but when the intended operation is `forEachRemaining`, you would need both, an `IntConsumer` to be passed to the `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt` for efficient processing and a `Consumer<Integer>` to handle those iterators which are not instances of `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt` and if you implement both within one class, you don’t need to perform a test at all, the iterator will do for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("with Collection (of Integer boxes)");
    filterAndPrint(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), i -> i>2);
    System.out.println("with IntStream (using primitive int values)");
    filterAndPrint(() -> IntStream.range(1, 4).iterator(), i -> i>2);
}
interface LoggingUnboxingIntConsumer extends IntConsumer, Consumer<Integer> {
    @Override default void accept(Integer t) {
        System.out.println("  unboxing " + t);
            accept(t.intValue());
    }
}
public static void filterAndPrint(Iterable<Integer> i, IntPredicate p) {
    i.iterator().forEachRemaining((LoggingUnboxingIntConsumer) (int value) -> {
        if(p.test(value)) System.out.println("  value "+value+" matches");
    });
}
```

```
with Collection (of Integer boxes)
  unboxing 1
  unboxing 2
  unboxing 3
  value 3 matches
with IntStream (using primitive int values)
  value 3 matches
```

This demonstrates that boxing operations are avoided when possible. This is part of [the contract of `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt.forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super Integer>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PrimitiveIterator.OfInt.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> #### Implementation Requirements:
>
> If the action is an instance of IntConsumer then it is cast to IntConsumer and passed to forEachRemaining(java.util.function.IntConsumer); otherwise the action is adapted to an instance of IntConsumer, by boxing the argument of IntConsumer, and then passed to forEachRemaining(java.util.function.IntConsumer).

This does not apply to single element processing via `hasNext()`/`next()`, but since your code is supposed to perform composition of `PrimitiveIterable.OfInt` only, the initial step is the only place where adaptation has to be done anyway

```
public static PrimitiveIterator.OfInt adapt(Iterator<Integer> it) {
    return it instanceof PrimitiveIterator.OfInt? (PrimitiveIterator.OfInt)it:
      new PrimitiveIterator.OfInt() {
        public int nextInt() { return it.next(); }
        public boolean hasNext() { return it.hasNext(); }
        public Integer next() { return it.next(); }
      };
}
```

After having created this method once, you may use it at all places where you accept an `Iterable`, e.g.

```
public static FilterIteratorInt filter(Iterable<Integer> iter, IntPredicate filter) {
    return new FilterIteratorInt(adapt(iter.iterator()), filter);
}
```

But note that this “iterator composition” looks very much like a reinvention of the Stream API (or `IntStream` API specifically)…

Comment: Thanks a lot for much to learn and think about! The last remark is specifically interesting. I have gained the impression that the "functional" features (including streams) of Java 8 are more intended as syntactic sugar, certainly enhancing expressibility a lot (and I do cherish that). I yet have to see whether more complex compositions (consisting of sets of iterators combined in specific ways) can be covered by them.

I am hopeful your hints may yet lead to a good solution as soon as I understand the whole concept of streams a lot better.